# Stream with xuggle to a red5 instance and making it all jnlp based

Tags: java, red5, rtmp, xuggle

Let's assume I have Xuggle recording the screen of the client in a video. Let's now assume I want to stream that video (while it is still being recorded) to my red 5 instance located in

```
localhost:1935/live
```

Is it at all possible to do this in a  programmatic  way(Java) and how should I open a connection to the stream to send IPackets. I assume I should use an IContainer instance to open a connection to the red5 instance but I have trouble understanding the documentation.

Some code sample will be invaluable.

A bonus question:

Has somebody managed to make Xuggle streaming jnlp-based?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/ it's a webstart solution for screen sharing.. You might be able to get some hints looking at the jar file. Sorry I can't help more, I'm not much of a java guy ;)

Comment: Did so a loong time ago. The thing is that there is only one screen share solution that uses the h264 codec which performs better than the open source SVC1 and SVC2 codecs which are widely implemented (also by me). Xuggler is nice in that it has powerful encoding capabilities as it is wrapped around ffmpeg, and they are really fast as it uses native encoding.